# Selenium webdriver takes 25 mins to identify and click an element

Tags: performance, selenium, time, wait, salesforce-lightning

This is Salesforce application with selenium Java.

Scenario:
Login to Salesforce with username, password and click on login

After that click on account tab in the Salesforce homepage.

Issue:
Salesforce login functionality is working fine. No issues.
After login to Salesforce it take 23 mins to perform the next action (click on Account tab link)
Here I used explicit wait of presence of element for 30 secs for the account tab link before click operation.
My script is not getting failed. I am not getting any timeout exception or no such element exception and my script is successful only after 23 mins (it takes 23 mins to identify element and click an element)

With same selenium code I tried with different Salesforce application but this time everything works as expected(after login I am able to click on account tab link). I never change the code. I just changed the application URL

I am thinking there might be an issue with application.but I am not sure about exact issue.

At least I should have received timeout or no such element exception
Or my script should have executed right after login without 23 mins of delay

I tried all the possible options like Page load strategy, fluent wait and explicit wait. Nothing works for me

Comment: When you login manually, how long does it take to load the page?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to implement a retry such that if the request isn't completed within 30 seconds (or whatever), try it again?

Comment: @itronic1990, when we login manually Page load completes instantly. Even in automation also Page load completes fast. No issues with pageload.

Comment: Thanks! We will implement retry logic. It may work with  retry logic but it should work without that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing cannot read property 'defaultview' of undefined. Or
If you are unable to perform any actions on Salesforce homepage or
If selenium web driver takes much time to perform the actions in Salesforce home page or
If your script is working fine with debug mode and not in run mode, please follow the below steps:

1. Launch the Salesforce URL
2. Do not login immediately, this will create the above problems instead apply some wait ( Apply thread.sleep for 8 to 10 sec)

3)Enter username and password and click on login button

4. now you are all set. Your are good to perform any actions in SF home page.

Thanks!

Comment: How does the wait in the login page helps ?